# I don't know why the object comes out to Null even if I use the @ModelAttribute

Tags: java, html, spring-boot

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBAVi.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DMiE.png)
I don't know why the object comes out to Null even if I use the model attribute

I don't know because it hasn't been fixed even when I change the value of the model attribute. I need help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off writing the source code yourself instead of the image.

if you using @ModelAttribute need setter method.

I can't see your Member class. but maybe your member_id variable does not set setter method. so you have to make a setter method.

```
public void setMember_id(String member_id) {
    this.member_id = member_id;
}
```

if you using lombok annotation just add @Setter annotation on you class name

```
@Setter
public class Member ...
```

And because of @RequestBody it can be confusing. Because it doesn't need a setter.